# sql calculations on varchar(5) [hh]:mm

Tags: sql-server, datetime, time, datediff, dateadd

Would you be able to help me out here, please?

I've got a column with varchar(5) values like [hh]:mm eg. 7:30, 13:15, 10:45, 9:00 etc.
I'm using datediff() to calculate the time difference between those values. Everything goes smooth until a value grater than 23:59 appears.
I tried converting the column to time, datetime and so on but everytime i got the same result -> the value is "out of range". 
Tried converting to decimal with no luck.. 
tried dateadd(hour,0,@value)... i'm out of ideas.
Please advice.

I'm on MS SQL 2012

-UPDATE-
sorry Guys, I didn't make myself clear about the problem. When I said time I meant duration (not a specific time during the day).
I store a time spend on some task. It might be 1 hour but it can even be 100 hours in total (during a month let's say). In excel I would use [hh]:mm format iso hh:mm to get this.
The [hh]:mm from Excel is exactly what I'm looking for in SQL but cannot find it.
Is varchar(5) an appropriate format to store such data ?

Comment: How do you get a time greater then 23:59, do you mean 00:00?

Comment: Well if a value is less than 00:00 or Greater than 23:59 than it isnt a time value. You need to find these invalid values in your database and scrap them, And this is why you should always use appropriate data types when creating tables so you dont endup with garbage data in your database.

Comment: It will help you if store your data in the appropriate data types

Comment: Hello Guys, thank you very much for Your comments. Please see the update. By "time" i meant number of hours spend on some work - it might be more than 24 hours because it's not restricted to one day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert (non time) values in HH:MM format extract the hours, convert to minutes then add the minutes;

```
cast(left(fld, charindex(':', fld) - 1) as int) * 60 + cast(substring(fld, charindex(':', fld) + 1, len(fld)) as int)
```

You can then compare them directly or add them to a date/time usinf `dateadd` with the `minutes` flag.

Comment: aaah I see where You're getting at. Will try it later and let You know if it worked. Looks like it might do the job. Thank You.

Comment: I followed Your train of thoughts and went with a bit simpler (to me) command: 
​select left(time,len(time)-3)*60 + right(time,2)  from table ///
thanks a lot! take care.

Answer (score 0):

I think trying to Convert Non-Time values into time guessing what User intended when he/she was enterning data can lead to wrong data and wrong results.

No data is better than Wrong Data. Therefore I would do a check on values if it is a valid time value take difference of it otherwise just ignore it.

Something like this.....

**Test Data**

Imagine you have two columns `StartTime` and `EndTime` both of `VARCHAR(5)` data type.

Now some of the values are invalid time values

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (StartTime VARCHAR(5), EndTime VARCHAR(5))

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
('09:00' , '15:00'),
('10:00' , '17:00'),
('15:00' , '24:30'),     --<-- Invalid Endtime
('25:00' , '15:00')      --<-- Invalid StartTime
```

**Query**

Using `ISDATE()` function only take difference of starttime and endtime when both are valid time values else just ignore them.

`ISDATE()` return 1 if the passed value is a Valid `DATETIME`, `DATE`or `TIME` etc value. and 0 if it is not.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN  ISDATE(StartTime) = 1 AND ISDATE(EndTime) = 1
        THEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartTime, EndTime)
       END
FROM @TABLE
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═════════════════╗
║ Datediff_Result ║
╠═════════════════╣
║ 6               ║
║ 7               ║
║ NULL            ║
║ NULL            ║
╚═════════════════╝
```

Comment: Hello M.Ali Thank You for Your replay. The problem is I would like to store "duration" not "time". That was the reason to store it as varchar(5) not as 'time'. I added update to the question to make it more clear. Sorry for being imprecise. Please let me know what You think.